# Oracle Apex: Region source(apex_util.prepare_url)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

This is a line in the region source for a dashboard

apex_util.prepare_url( 'f?p='||:APP_ID||':4:'||:APP_SESSION||':::4,RIR:IRGTE_ORDER_DATE:'||:P1_THIS_MONTH ) as url

There is a button on the region which set the value for [:IRGTE_ORDER_DATE as shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPJG5.png)

The value for :P1_THIS_MONTH is to_char(sysdate ,'MM')||'01'||to_char(sysdate ,'YYYY'), as this is a packaged application i wanted to know what is IRGTE_ORDER_DATE in the source code above.

Thanks
Rakesh

Comment: I cant see any item with the name IRGTE_ORDER_DATE on page 4

Comment: You could ask whoever wrote this application that you're using, but I'd guess it's probably an [application-level item](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/bldapp_item_app.htm#HTMDB05034)

Answer (score 2):

This is the syntax used to dynamically create a filter when linking to a page containing one or more interactive reports: IR[region static ID]_

The IR prefix indicates that this an interactive report parameter. 
In this case a [region static ID] has been omitted, so the page must only contain one IR region. 
GTE indicates that the filter operator is "greater than or equal to". 
ORDER_DATE is the column to be filtered.
The filter value is that referenced by the &P1_THIS_MONTH. substitution string.

Comment: sorry i got this answer from another site thought it would be helpful to others.